# Background image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, c#-4.0, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to get my head round Bootstrap background images.  Can anyone help on the right syntax for displaying a background image when the file is local.  Specifically I've got two alternative lines in my page html

```
<body class ="bg-image" style="background-image: 
url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/76.jpg');height:100vh;">
<body class ="bg-image" style="background-image: 
url('/wwwroot/Images/gymEquipment.jpg');height:100vh;">
```

The first one works and the second local one doesn't.  Any corrections greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: This doesn't seem like a C# or a Bootstrap question. Is the image available at that path?

Comment: True, probably not a c# question. My apologies.  And yes, the image is available at that URL.

Comment: Well then there's nothing here to indicate a problem. FYI, Bootstrap has classes for `100vh`.  No need for inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full page background image**

we can easily make this background image to cover the full available space and make it a full-page background image.

Just replace height: 400px; with height: 100vh;

vh stands for viewport height.

height: 100vh; means 100% of available height.

```
<!-- Background image -->
<div
  class="bg-image"
  style="
    background-image: url('https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/standard/city/041.webp');
    height: 100vh;
  "
></div>
<!-- Background image -->
```

> Note: If you want to stretch the image to the full available height and width remember to use the image with enough high resolution. However, be careful not to overdo it. Heigh-resolution images weigh a lot and can slow down your website.

*For More Information*: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/content-styles/background-image/